# Create new column to existing csv with values of percentages obtained from division of values to pivot table vector?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, pivot-table

I want to create new column to an existing csv. This column is Percentage obtained by division and times 100 units as below(Look the commented arrow on the full code):
dfb['cm_target_perc']=cm_inc/[dfb['cm_target']*100*len(cm_inc)

What I want is to generate new column where each value should be obtained by dividing cm_inc which is a vector of pivot table to dfb['cm_target'] which its value is 40 for every row multipying by 100.

Here is my full Jupyter Notebook code:

```
from plotly.offline import init_notebook_mode, iplot
from plotly import graph_objs as go
init_notebook_mode(connected = True)
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import timedelta, datetime, tzinfo
import time
from datetime import datetime as dt


dfb=pd.read_csv('https://www.dropbox.com/s/90y07129zn351z9/test_data.csv?dl=1', encoding="latin-1", infer_datetime_format=True, parse_dates=['date'], skipinitialspace=True)
dfb["date"]=pd.to_datetime(dfb['date']) 

dfb["site"]=dfb["site"].astype("category")
cm_inc=dfb[dfb.site == 5].pivot_table(index='date', values = 'site', aggfunc = {  'site' : 'count' }  )
dfb['cm_target'] = [40]*len(dfb)

#===>>>#dfb['cm_target_perc']=cm_inc/[dfb['cm_target']*100*len(cm_inc)

dfb.to_csv('test_data.csv', index=False)


indexes =pd.to_datetime(cm_inc.index) 

dates_indexes = pd.to_datetime(cm_inc.index) 

data = [
    go.Bar(x=indexes, 
           y=dfb['cm_target'],
           text=dfb['cm_target'],
           textposition = 'auto',
           name='Target Site A', 
           base=0
          ),
    go.Bar(x=indexes, 
           y=cm_inc['site'],
           text=cm_inc['site'],
           textposition = 'auto',
           name='Enroll Site A', 
           base=0,
           #width=2  # Width value varies depending on number of samples in data
           )
]

layout = go.Layout(
    barmode='stack',
    xaxis=dict(
        showticklabels=True,
        ticktext=dates_indexes,
        tickvals=[i for i in indexes],
    )
)

fig = dict(data = data, layout = layout)
iplot(fig, show_link=False)
```

Question: How to change it and fix this error: 
ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 1239, placement implies 1

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if your `dfb['cm_target']` are all 40, why not just `dfb['cm_target_perc']=cm_inc/40*100*len(cm_inc)` ?

Comment: `cm_inc` is a DataFrame, use its column instead

Comment: @iamanigeeit, cm_inc is pivot_table vector. You say its dataframe, so how to call its column? Thanks

Comment: you can do `cm_inc.site` or `cm_inc['site']` (`cm_inc` is a DataFrame with 1 column)

Comment: @iamanigeeit, it accepts but only creates new column with empty data.

Comment: @iamanigeeit, the trouble is to select only the values of cm_inc vector and ignoring the date column.Any idea?Thanks

Comment: Ah, i see why. `cm_inc` is indexed on `date` but `dfb` is not. You should  `dfb.set_index('date', inplace=True)` before `dfb['cm_target_perc']=`...

Comment: @iamanigeeit, doesn't work.

Comment: what is not working? "doesn't work" is extremely unhelpful. i tried your code with `dfb.set_index('date', inplace=True)` and `dfb['cm_target_perc']=cm_inc/40*100*len(cm_inc)` and it works as expected. you will have some missing data because your `cm_inc` does not have all the dates that your `dfb` has.

Comment: @iamanigeeit, its clear that dfb is dataset with all dates and cm_inc is dataframe resulting from pivot_table of dfb. So, all I want is to plot only the row where I have data within pivot_table i.e. pivot_table value and divide it by cm_target in the same row(remmember for this example is   same value along the column but i could have differente values) and assign that new column to csv as cm_target_perc. This cm_targer_perc will have only values rows thats exists in cm_inc allowing me to have 2 columns(cm_inc and cm_target_perf) to plot overlapped barchart as desired.

Comment: @iamanigeeit, All I want is to have or in the pivot_table one more column which i will have percentagem values or add that new column to dfb dataset to let me allow compare these two columns in barchart: target vs achieved in percentages and not just with achieved in values.Thanks

Comment: @iamanigeeit When I follow your tip in the dfb just creates an empty cm_target_perc without values

Comment: see if my answer helps

Answer (score 0):

While it is not new column, it can deliver the desired results as below:

```
cm_achived_perc=cm_inc.loc[:]/40*100
%matplotlib inline
cm_achived_perc.plot(kind = 'bar')
```

[image]

Comment: But i need to plot two barchart not just this.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

Replacing your lines

```
dfb['cm_target'] = [40]*len(dfb)
dfb['cm_target_perc']=cm_inc/[dfb['cm_target']*100*len(cm_inc)
```

With

```
dfb['cm_target'] = [random.randint(40,100) for i in range(len(dfb))] # Create random values
dfb.set_index('date', inplace=True)
dfb['cm_inc'] = cm_inc.site # Copy over the values since you have multiple dates in dfb
dfb['cm_target_perc'] = cm_inc / dfb.cm_target * 100
```

Gives me this dfb

```
           site         received             sent  cm_target  cm_inc  cm_target_perc
date                                                                                
2018-07-10    2              NaN              NaN         58    20.0       34.482759
2018-07-10    2              NaN              NaN         63    20.0       31.746032
2018-07-11    2              NaN              NaN         67    20.0       29.850746
2018-07-11    2              NaN              NaN        100    20.0       20.000000
```